# Breakpoint 2.1 Error Parse/Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, breakpoints

Here is the entire delegate, but whenever I run the app I get a breakpoint at `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

    {[Parse setApplicationId:@"ycWShHVTsY7Xawt0dupTN1YMWFeyMLlhG7K9R0rZ"
                   clientKey:@"8AmzExUoqvmppa5k3eaS37RBNB6c1StmlysvvjBr"];}

    {[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];}

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController* initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;


}



    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
    }


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

/*- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}   */

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: (lldb)  <-- This is the output of the crash

Comment: What do you mean, you get a breakpoint? Do you have a breakpoint enabled for "all exceptions"? Is there any error message or stack trace?

Comment: Alright, I got what you were saying lol, The Xcode IDE and Objective C is new for me. I deleted all breakpoints but now I get the Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT when I launch the app

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported libc++ to your project?

It isnt a breakpoint the way you think it is, It is essentially the compiler telling your device to stop computing code sent from XCode, SIGABRT stands for Signal Abort

SIGABRT rises when an object receives unimplemented message. How many warnings does your app have? Try surfing through them and find the ones that warn you "some object may not respond to some selector", if you clean your app from all of these, you'll most probably get it working correctly.

Comment: My app has 25 warnings. LOL. Alright man, I'll try to clear the warnings and I hope it runs. Also what's libc++?

Answer (score 0):

You should call initializeFacebook only after setting the appId and clientKey.

Try this:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"ycWShHVTsY7Xawt0dupTN1YMWFeyMLlhG7K9R0rZ"
               clientKey:@"8AmzExUoqvmppa5k3eaS37RBNB6c1StmlysvvjBr"];

[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
```

Instead of this:

```
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

{[Parse setApplicationId:@"ycWShHVTsY7Xawt0dupTN1YMWFeyMLlhG7K9R0rZ"
               clientKey:@"8AmzExUoqvmppa5k3eaS37RBNB6c1StmlysvvjBr"];}

{[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];}
```

btw, I'd recommend creating another app in parse, now that you posted here these two keys are public and anyone can mess up with your data.

Comment: Easier than that would be to just reset Master key for this app. That would also render this public information useless without requiring a full data re-creation.